# Why is this not working? (Generic Equals Helper)

Tags: c#, generics, equals

**SOLVED!**
This works, I need to tell the compiler that T implements IEquatable of course...

```
public static bool secureEquals<T>(T obj1, object obj2)
    where T: class, IEquatable<T>
{...

public static bool secureEquals<T>(T obj1, T obj2)
    where T: class, IEquatable<T>
{....
```

---

Question:

I tried to put repeated functionality of IEquatable implementations and Equals overrides into a separate static class like so:

```
public static class EqualsHelper
{
    public static bool secureEquals<T>(T obj1, object obj2)
       where T : class
    {
        if (obj2 is T)
        {
            return secureEquals(obj1, obj2 as T);
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static bool secureEquals<T>(T obj1, T obj2)
    {
        if (obj1 == null)
        {
            if (obj2 != null)
                return false;
        }
        else
        {
            if (!obj1.Equals(obj2)) //this calls Dummy.Equals(object other)!
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }


    public static bool secureEquals(double[] obj1, double[] obj2)
    {
        if (obj1.Length != obj2.Length)
            return false;

        for (int i = 0; i < obj1.Length; ++i)
        {
            if (obj1[i] != obj2[i])//ok for doubles if they are generated in the same way? I guess so!
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

public class Dummy : IEquatable<Dummy>
{
    public Dummy(string member)
    {
        _member = member;
    }

    private string _member;


    public virtual bool Equals(Dummy other)
    {
        return this._member == other._member;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object other)
    {
        return EqualsHelper.secureEquals(this, other);
    }

}

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dummy d1 = new Dummy("Hugo");
        Dummy d2 = new Dummy("Hugo");

        object d2obj = (object)d2;

        bool ret = d1.Equals(d2obj);
    }
```

The idea was:
 d1.Equals(d2obj) calls Dummy.Equals(object) calls EqualsHelper.secureEquals(T, obj) calls EqualsHelper.secureEquals(T, T) calls Dummy.Equals(Dummy).

The last call however calls Dummy.Equals(object), even though everything is typed to T there.

What am I missing?

PS: I know that replacing the call with:

```
            if (!((IEquatable<T>)obj1).Equals(obj2)) //this calls Dummy.Equals(object other)!
```

does the trick, but why is it not working otherwise?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why: because method invoke here is static typed, and the only available `Equals` involving a `T` with no generic constraint is `object.Equals(object)`. The exact same IL has to be able to handle **every** `T` - C# generics are not like C++ templates; no per-T overload resolution occurs.

As an aside: you might also want to look at `EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(obj1,obj2)`, which will handle `IEquatable<T>`, `Nullable<T>`, etc automatically:

```
public static bool secureEquals<T>(T obj1, object obj2) where T : class
{
    return EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(obj1, obj2 as T);
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(...)`?

Comment: Whats the advantage of using EqualityComparer?

Comment: @B3ret because it handles a few subtle rules automatically - for example, applying `IEquatable<T>`

Answer (score 4):

The `Equals` overload within `EqualsHelper.secureEquals` is resolved when `EqualsHelper` is compiled - and that code doesn't know whether `T` implements `IComparable<T>` or not, so all that's left is `Equals(Object)`. You can add a constraint to `T` which would make it use the right overload:

```
public static bool SecureEquals<T>(T obj1, T obj2) where T : IEquatable<T>
```

Of course, this would limit the classes with which you could use it.

(As an aside, note that I've renamed `secureEquals` to `SecureEquals` to comply with .NET naming conventions. I'd also not use the word "secure" here at all personally - there's nothing security-sensitive here.)

Answer (score 0):

Because in your `secureEquals` you have no constraints, and compiler always assumes Object.Equals exist. Add interface constraint for your T.